# Fundamental set of solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that if $y_1$ and $y_2$:

a. vanish at the same point in the interval $\alpha < t < \beta$ then they cannot forma  fundamental set of solutions on this interval.

So I know that a fundamental set of solutions can be written as $y(t)=c_1y_1(t)+c_2y_2(t)$

I am not sure exactly what my textbook means by "vanish"? Go to 0?

$y(t)=c_1*0+c_2*0$

So if both functions go to 0, no combination of them can equal y(t) unless y(t) is also 0

b. achieve a maximum or minimum at the same point in the interval $\alpha < t < \beta$  then they cannot form a fundamental set of solutions

I don't really know how to get started on these proofs at all, nor is it obvious to me why these are true

Comment: "Vanish" means that a function is zero at those points in consideration.

Comment: On another note, I have no idea if this is right, but the Wronskian will be equal to 0 if they vanish together based on page 135, meaning they are linearly dependent.